# Yitro's Daughters

Tags: names, parashas-shemos

Tzipporah is one of 7 daughters of Yitro according to Sh'mot 2:16

> וּלְכֹהֵ֥ן מִדְיָ֖ן שֶׁ֣בַע בָּנ֑וֹת וַתָּבֹ֣אנָה וַתִּדְלֶ֗נָה וַתְּמַלֶּ֙אנָה֙ אֶת־הָ֣רְהָטִ֔ים לְהַשְׁק֖וֹת צֹ֥אן אֲבִיהֶֽן׃

I have looked through the meforshim and medrashim on Sefaria but have been unable to find the names of the other six. Are their names recorded anywhere and, if so, what are those names?

Comment: According to some commentators, the seven daughters (Tzipora included) were actually his granddaughters. See Ibn Ezra to Shemot 10:28

Comment: If you go by the explanation that Putiel was another name for Yitro, then Elazar's (nameless) wife, mother of Pinchas, was one of them.

Comment: There's a vort presented here that maybe Yitro's seven names were linked to those of his daughters', but it appears to be mostly a sevara: http://www.toratreva.org/Joomla/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=19&Itemid=9  see "The seven names of Yitro and his seven daughters".

Comment: We might have expected Sefer HaYashar, which typically expands on these things, to list them. But it does not. https://books.google.com/books?id=8AHZ-l0u4n8C&lpg=RA1-PR17&dq=sefer%20ha%20yashar&pg=PA216#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @joshwaxman Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Some midrashim often fill in the names of minor characters. One prominent example is Sefer Hayashar. Thus, all the names of the wives of Yaakov's sons are listed in chapter 45:

[image: Sefer Hayashar wives' names]

And so in many other places. However, in the case of Tzippora's sisters, [Sefer Hayashar](https://books.google.com/books?id=8AHZ-l0u4n8C&lpg=RA1-PR17&dq=sefer%20ha%20yashar&pg=PA216#v=onepage&q&f=false), chapter 76 does not list it. Rather, verse 14 just describes them as the seven daughters of Reuel the Midianite.

Comment: maybe this is more of a meta topic, but is "you would think it would be here, but it isn't" an answer, itself?

Comment: though it might suggest that there is no place to find it. To your point, I first posted this as a comment above, basically for that reason, but then @IsaacMoses, who created / runs the site, suggested that I post it as an answer, so I did.